# Visual Studio-Cannot use browse dialogs such as Open File

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem anywhere.
Recently, I installed Visual Studio 2012, since there was elements in 2010 that are not avaliable and needed to use. I installed it and it worked fine for a while. However, it then wouldn't open at all and just crash at the start. It did the same thing to my Visual Studio 2010. I reinstalled both visual studios and the .net framework and this fixed the issue, but there is an even bigger issue now. Open buttons do not work at all within Visual Studio. For example, if I clicked Open Project or Add Reference, nothing happens. No error message, no dialog box, nothing.
I've tried to reinstall everything and nothing has worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you haven't already, try resetting all of your settings - it is possible they are corrupted. If that doesn't work, maybe uninstall all Visual Studio-related stuff first, then restart, then delete all the directories related to Visual Studio settings - under `%appdata%\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2010`, `%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`,  `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Visual Studio`, `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`, `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services`, `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio*`, and maybe others (particularly under Program Files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you have to start the TabletPCInput service in services

---

To dock Input Panel. Open Tablet PC Input Panel by clicking the Start button , clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, clicking Tablet PC, and then clicking Input Panel. Tap Tools, and then tap Dock at Top of Screen or Dock at Bottom of Screen.

Comment: No , Mostafa Shaeri , I faced the same problem  and it worked for me,

Comment: I started the service, restarted Visual Studio, and now I can all of the dialog boxes will show up again.  Thanks!

Comment: Using Windows through VirtualBox I had the same issue. It saved the day!